# Adapt Crypto API (VBA) to use with Access 2010 64 bit

Tags: vba, cryptography

Hi i've a VBA module that works fine in 32 bit Office Ambient (Access 2010). I need to adapt code to run correctly also in 64 bit Office Ambient.

In details i can't understand the structure of handles and datatype for

Private Declare Function CryptGetProvParam Lib "advapi32.dll"....
Private Declare Function CryptDeriveKey Lib "advapi32.dll"....
Private Declare Function CryptEncrypt Lib "advapi32.dll"......
Private Declare Function CryptDestroyKey Lib "advapi32.dll"...
Private Declare Function CryptDecrypt Lib "advapi32.dll".....

I've looked for many times on internet but i didn't find any references for Crypto API to understand details for each function.

Thanks in advance for your time.

**Updated**: I've defined the code tu runs well but i've a little problem.
The code runs well in 32 BIT versione, but in 64 Bit version produces a wrong decrypted string when i pass to decrypt function a string that has lenght greater than 3 characters. If i pass 2 or 3 characters string lenght, decrypt produces the correct key but if i pass 4 or more characters everytime has been produced a different string.

This following code produces correct result

EncryptionCSPConnect
sEncrypted = EncryptData("aa", MY_PASSWORD)
EncryptionCSPDisconnect

EncryptionCSPConnect
sDecrypted = DecryptData(sEncrypted , MY_PASSWORD)
EncryptionCSPDisconnect

**This following code produces UNCORRECT result**

EncryptionCSPConnect
sEncrypted = EncryptData("example", MY_PASSWORD)
EncryptionCSPDisconnect

EncryptionCSPConnect
sDecrypted = DecryptData(sEncrypted , MY_PASSWORD)
EncryptionCSPDisconnect

```
    Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" _
                            (ByRef phProv As LongPtr, ByVal pszContainer As String, ByVal pszProvider As String, _
                             ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptCreateHash Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, ByVal algid As Long, ByVal hKey As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                             ByRef phHash As LongPtr) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptDestroyHash Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hHash As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hHash As LongPtr, pbData As Any, ByVal cbData As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptGetHashParam Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hHash As LongPtr, ByVal dwParam As Long, pbData As Any, ByRef pcbData As Long, _
                             ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptDeriveKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, ByVal algid As Long, ByVal hBaseData As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
     ByRef phKey As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptDestroyKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hKey As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptEncrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, ByVal hHash As LongPtr, ByVal Final As Boolean, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
     ByVal pbData As String, ByRef pdwDataLen As Long, ByVal dwBufLen As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptDecrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, _
     ByVal hHash As LongPtr, _
     ByVal Final As Boolean, _
     ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
     ByVal pbData As String, _
     ByRef pdwDataLen As Long) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptGetProvParam Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, _
     ByVal dwParam As Long, _
     ByRef pbData As Any, _
     ByRef pdwDataLen As Long, _
     ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long


#Else

    Private Declare Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" _
                                (ByRef phProv As Long, ByVal pszContainer As String, ByVal pszProvider As String, _
                                 ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CryptCreateHash Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal Algid As Long, ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                                 ByRef phHash As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CryptDestroyHash Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hHash As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hHash As Long, pbData As Any, ByVal cbData As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CryptGetHashParam Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal dwParam As Long, pbData As Any, ByRef pcbData As Long, _
                                 ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptDeriveKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal Algid As Long, ByVal hBaseData As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
         ByRef phKey As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptDestroyKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptEncrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal Final As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
         ByVal pbData As String, ByRef pdwDataLen As Long, ByVal dwBufLen As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptDecrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hKey As Long, _
         ByVal hHash As Long, _
         ByVal Final As Long, _
         ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
         ByVal pbData As String, _
         ByRef pdwDataLen As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptGetProvParam Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hProv As Long, _
         ByVal dwParam As Long, _
         ByRef pbData As Any, _
         ByRef pdwDataLen As Long, _
         ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long


#End If

Private Const SERVICE_PROVIDER As String = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
Private Const KEY_CONTAINER As String = "Metallica"
Private Const PROV_RSA_FULL As Long = 1
Private Const PP_NAME As Long = 4
Private Const PP_CONTAINER As Long = 6
Private Const CRYPT_NEWKEYSET As Long = 8
Private Const ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT As Long = 24576
Private Const ALG_CLASS_HASH As Long = 32768
Private Const ALG_TYPE_ANY As Long = 0
Private Const ALG_TYPE_STREAM As Long = 2048
Private Const ALG_SID_RC4 As Long = 1
Private Const ALG_SID_MD5 As Long = 3
Private Const CALG_MD5 As Long = ((ALG_CLASS_HASH Or ALG_TYPE_ANY) Or ALG_SID_MD5)
Private Const CALG_RC4 As Long = ((ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT Or ALG_TYPE_STREAM) Or ALG_SID_RC4)
Private Const ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM As Long = CALG_RC4
Private Const NUMBER_ENCRYPT_PASSWORD As String = "´o¸sçPQ]"

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private hCryptProv As LongPtr
#Else
    Private hCryptProv As Long
#End If

Public Function EncryptionCSPConnect() As Boolean
    'Function Adapted
    'Get handle to CSP

    If CryptAcquireContext(hCryptProv, KEY_CONTAINER, SERVICE_PROVIDER, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET) = 0 Then
        If CryptAcquireContext(hCryptProv, KEY_CONTAINER, SERVICE_PROVIDER, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0) = 0 Then
            HandleError "Error during CryptAcquireContext for a new key container." & vbCrLf & _
                        "A container with this name probably already exists."
            EncryptionCSPConnect = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    EncryptionCSPConnect = True
End Function

Public Sub EncryptionCSPDisconnect()
    'Release provider handle.
   'Function Adapted

    If hCryptProv <> 0 Then
        CryptReleaseContext hCryptProv, 0
    End If
End Sub

Public Function EncryptData(ByVal data As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
    Dim sEncrypted As String
    Dim lEncryptionCount As Long
    Dim sTempPassword As String

    'It is possible that the normal encryption will give you a string
    'containing cr or lf characters which make it difficult to write to files
    'Do a loop changing the password and keep encrypting until the result is ok
    'To be able to decrypt we need to also store the number of loops in the result

    'Try first encryption
    lEncryptionCount = 0
    sTempPassword = Password & lEncryptionCount
    sEncrypted = EncryptDecrypt(data, sTempPassword, True)

    'Loop if this contained a bad character
    Do While (InStr(1, sEncrypted, vbCr) > 0) _
          Or (InStr(1, sEncrypted, vbLf) > 0) _
          Or (InStr(1, sEncrypted, Chr$(0)) > 0) _
          Or (InStr(1, sEncrypted, vbTab) > 0)

        'Try the next password
        lEncryptionCount = lEncryptionCount + 1
        sTempPassword = Password & lEncryptionCount
        sEncrypted = EncryptDecrypt(data, sTempPassword, True)

        'Don't go on for ever, 1 billion attempts should be plenty
        If lEncryptionCount = 99999999 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 999, "EncryptData", "This data cannot be successfully encrypted"
            EncryptData = ""
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop

    'Build encrypted string, starting with number of encryption iterations
    EncryptData = EncryptNumber(lEncryptionCount) & sEncrypted
End Function

Public Function DecryptData(ByVal data As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
    Dim lEncryptionCount As Long
    Dim sDecrypted As String
    Dim sTempPassword As String

    'When encrypting we may have gone through a number of iterations
    'How many did we go through?
    lEncryptionCount = DecryptNumber(Mid$(data, 1, 8))

    'start with the last password and work back
    sTempPassword = Password & lEncryptionCount
    sDecrypted = EncryptDecrypt(Mid$(data, 9), sTempPassword, False)

    DecryptData = sDecrypted
End Function

Public Function GetCSPDetails() As String
    Dim lLength As Long
    Dim yContainer() As Byte

    If hCryptProv = 0 Then
        GetCSPDetails = "Not connected to CSP"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'For developer info, show what the CSP & container name is
    lLength = 1000
    ReDim yContainer(lLength)
    If CryptGetProvParam(hCryptProv, PP_NAME, yContainer(0), lLength, 0) <> 0 Then
        GetCSPDetails = "Cryptographic Service Provider name: " & ByteToStr(yContainer, lLength)
    End If
    lLength = 1000
    ReDim yContainer(lLength)
    If CryptGetProvParam(hCryptProv, PP_CONTAINER, yContainer(0), lLength, 0) <> 0 Then
        GetCSPDetails = GetCSPDetails & vbCrLf & "Key Container name: " & ByteToStr(yContainer, lLength)
    End If
End Function

Private Function EncryptDecrypt(ByVal data As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal encrypt As Boolean) As String

    #If Win64 Then
       Dim hHash As LongPtr
       Dim hKey  As LongPtr
       Dim hHashNull As LongPtr
       Dim hKeyNull As LongPtr

       hHashNull = 0&
       hKeyNull = 0&

    #Else
       Dim hHash As Long
        Dim hKey As Long
        Dim hHashNull As Long
       Dim hKeyNull As Long
    #End If


    Dim lLength As Long
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim GetValue As Boolean

    If hCryptProv = 0 Then
        HandleError "Not connected to CSP"
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    'The data will be encrypted with a session key derived from the
    'password.
    'The session key will be recreated when the data is decrypted
    'only if the password used to create the key is available.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Create a hash object.
    GetValue = CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_MD5, hKeyNull, 0, hHash)

    If GetValue = False Then
        HandleError "Error during CryptCreateHash!"
    End If

    'Hash the password.
    If CryptHashData(hHash, Password, Len(Password), 0) = 0 Then
        HandleError "Error during CryptHashData."
    End If

    'Derive a session key from the hash object.
    If CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM, hHash, 0, hKey) = 0 Then
        HandleError "Error during CryptDeriveKey!"
    End If

    'Do the work
    sTemp = data
    lLength = Len(data)
    If encrypt Then
        'Encrypt data.
        If CryptEncrypt(hKey, hHashNull, True, 0, sTemp, lLength, lLength) = 0 Then
            HandleError "Error during CryptEncrypt."
        End If
    Else
        'Encrypt data.
        GetValue = CryptDecrypt(hKey, hHashNull, True, 0, sTemp, lLength)
        If GetValue = 0 Then
            HandleError "Error during CryptDecrypt."
        End If
    End If

    'This is what we return.
    EncryptDecrypt = Mid$(sTemp, 1, lLength)

    'Destroy session key.
    If hKey <> 0 Then
        CryptDestroyKey hKey
    End If

    'Destroy hash object.
    If hHash <> 0 Then
        CryptDestroyHash hHash
    End If
End Function

Private Sub HandleError(ByVal error As String)
    'You could write the error to the screen or to a file
    Debug.Print error
End Sub

Private Function ByteToStr(ByRef ByteArray() As Byte, ByVal lLength As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ByteArray) To (LBound(ByteArray) + lLength)
        ByteToStr = ByteToStr & Chr$(ByteArray(i))
    Next i
End Function

Private Function EncryptNumber(ByVal lNumber As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sNumber As String

    sNumber = Format$(lNumber, "00000000")

    For i = 1 To 8
        EncryptNumber = EncryptNumber & Chr$(Asc(Mid$(NUMBER_ENCRYPT_PASSWORD, i, 1)) + Val(Mid$(sNumber, i, 1)))
    Next i
End Function

Private Function DecryptNumber(ByVal sNumber As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 8
        DecryptNumber = (10 * DecryptNumber) + (Asc(Mid$(sNumber, i, 1)) - Asc(Mid$(NUMBER_ENCRYPT_PASSWORD, i, 1)))
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**: The problem was the function

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hHash As LongPtr, pbData As Any, ByVal cbData As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

was completely wrong because is written to accept BYTE type and not STRING data.

Exact is

For 64 Bit:

Private Declare PTRSAFE Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hHash As Longptr, _
         ByVal pbData As String, _
         ByVal dwDataLen As Long, _
         ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

For 32 BIT:

Private Declare Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hHash As Long, _
         ByVal pbData As String, _
         ByVal dwDataLen As Long, _
         ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Following is the definitely listing. Thanks to all.

```
    Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" _
                            (ByRef phProv As LongPtr, ByVal pszContainer As String, ByVal pszProvider As String, _
                             ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptCreateHash Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, ByVal algid As Long, ByVal hKey As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                             ByRef phHash As LongPtr) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptDestroyHash Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hHash As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe  Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hHash As Long, _
         ByVal pbData As String, _
         ByVal dwDataLen As Long, _
         ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long


Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptGetHashParam Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                            (ByVal hHash As LongPtr, ByVal dwParam As Long, pbData As Any, ByRef pcbData As Long, _
                             ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptDeriveKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, ByVal algid As Long, ByVal hBaseData As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
     ByRef phKey As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptDestroyKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hKey As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptEncrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, ByVal hHash As LongPtr, ByVal Final As Boolean, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
     ByVal pbData As String, ByRef pdwDataLen As Long, ByVal dwBufLen As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptDecrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, _
     ByVal hHash As LongPtr, _
     ByVal Final As Boolean, _
     ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
     ByVal pbData As String, _
     ByRef pdwDataLen As Long) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CryptGetProvParam Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    (ByVal hProv As LongPtr, _
     ByVal dwParam As Long, _
     ByRef pbData As Any, _
     ByRef pdwDataLen As Long, _
     ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long


#Else

    Private Declare Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" _
                                (ByRef phProv As Long, ByVal pszContainer As String, ByVal pszProvider As String, _
                                 ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CryptCreateHash Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal Algid As Long, ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                                 ByRef phHash As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CryptDestroyHash Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hHash As Long) As Long

   Private Declare PtrSafe  Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hHash As Long, _
         ByVal pbData As String, _
         ByVal dwDataLen As Long, _
         ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptGetHashParam Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                                (ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal dwParam As Long, pbData As Any, ByRef pcbData As Long, _
                                 ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptDeriveKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal Algid As Long, ByVal hBaseData As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
         ByRef phKey As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptDestroyKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptEncrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal Final As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
         ByVal pbData As String, ByRef pdwDataLen As Long, ByVal dwBufLen As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptDecrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hKey As Long, _
         ByVal hHash As Long, _
         ByVal Final As Long, _
         ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
         ByVal pbData As String, _
         ByRef pdwDataLen As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CryptGetProvParam Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        (ByVal hProv As Long, _
         ByVal dwParam As Long, _
         ByRef pbData As Any, _
         ByRef pdwDataLen As Long, _
         ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long


#End If

Private Const SERVICE_PROVIDER As String = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
Private Const KEY_CONTAINER As String = "Metallica"
Private Const PROV_RSA_FULL As Long = 1
Private Const PP_NAME As Long = 4
Private Const PP_CONTAINER As Long = 6
Private Const CRYPT_NEWKEYSET As Long = 8
Private Const ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT As Long = 24576
Private Const ALG_CLASS_HASH As Long = 32768
Private Const ALG_TYPE_ANY As Long = 0
Private Const ALG_TYPE_STREAM As Long = 2048
Private Const ALG_SID_RC4 As Long = 1
Private Const ALG_SID_MD5 As Long = 3
Private Const CALG_MD5 As Long = ((ALG_CLASS_HASH Or ALG_TYPE_ANY) Or ALG_SID_MD5)
Private Const CALG_RC4 As Long = ((ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT Or ALG_TYPE_STREAM) Or ALG_SID_RC4)
Private Const ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM As Long = CALG_RC4
Private Const NUMBER_ENCRYPT_PASSWORD As String = "´o¸sçPQ]"

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private hCryptProv As LongPtr
#Else
    Private hCryptProv As Long
#End If

Public Function EncryptionCSPConnect() As Boolean
    'Function Adapted
    'Get handle to CSP

    If CryptAcquireContext(hCryptProv, KEY_CONTAINER, SERVICE_PROVIDER, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET) = 0 Then
        If CryptAcquireContext(hCryptProv, KEY_CONTAINER, SERVICE_PROVIDER, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0) = 0 Then
            HandleError "Error during CryptAcquireContext for a new key container." & vbCrLf & _
                        "A container with this name probably already exists."
            EncryptionCSPConnect = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    EncryptionCSPConnect = True
End Function

Public Sub EncryptionCSPDisconnect()
    'Release provider handle.
   'Function Adapted

    If hCryptProv <> 0 Then
        CryptReleaseContext hCryptProv, 0
    End If
End Sub

Public Function EncryptData(ByVal data As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
    Dim sEncrypted As String
    Dim lEncryptionCount As Long
    Dim sTempPassword As String

    'It is possible that the normal encryption will give you a string
    'containing cr or lf characters which make it difficult to write to files
    'Do a loop changing the password and keep encrypting until the result is ok
    'To be able to decrypt we need to also store the number of loops in the result

    'Try first encryption
    lEncryptionCount = 0
    sTempPassword = Password & lEncryptionCount
    sEncrypted = EncryptDecrypt(data, sTempPassword, True)

    'Loop if this contained a bad character
    Do While (InStr(1, sEncrypted, vbCr) > 0) _
          Or (InStr(1, sEncrypted, vbLf) > 0) _
          Or (InStr(1, sEncrypted, Chr$(0)) > 0) _
          Or (InStr(1, sEncrypted, vbTab) > 0)

        'Try the next password
        lEncryptionCount = lEncryptionCount + 1
        sTempPassword = Password & lEncryptionCount
        sEncrypted = EncryptDecrypt(data, sTempPassword, True)

        'Don't go on for ever, 1 billion attempts should be plenty
        If lEncryptionCount = 99999999 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 999, "EncryptData", "This data cannot be successfully encrypted"
            EncryptData = ""
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop

    'Build encrypted string, starting with number of encryption iterations
    EncryptData = EncryptNumber(lEncryptionCount) & sEncrypted
End Function

Public Function DecryptData(ByVal data As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
    Dim lEncryptionCount As Long
    Dim sDecrypted As String
    Dim sTempPassword As String

    'When encrypting we may have gone through a number of iterations
    'How many did we go through?
    lEncryptionCount = DecryptNumber(Mid$(data, 1, 8))

    'start with the last password and work back
    sTempPassword = Password & lEncryptionCount
    sDecrypted = EncryptDecrypt(Mid$(data, 9), sTempPassword, False)

    DecryptData = sDecrypted
End Function

Public Function GetCSPDetails() As String
    Dim lLength As Long
    Dim yContainer() As Byte

    If hCryptProv = 0 Then
        GetCSPDetails = "Not connected to CSP"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'For developer info, show what the CSP & container name is
    lLength = 1000
    ReDim yContainer(lLength)
    If CryptGetProvParam(hCryptProv, PP_NAME, yContainer(0), lLength, 0) <> 0 Then
        GetCSPDetails = "Cryptographic Service Provider name: " & ByteToStr(yContainer, lLength)
    End If
    lLength = 1000
    ReDim yContainer(lLength)
    If CryptGetProvParam(hCryptProv, PP_CONTAINER, yContainer(0), lLength, 0) <> 0 Then
        GetCSPDetails = GetCSPDetails & vbCrLf & "Key Container name: " & ByteToStr(yContainer, lLength)
    End If
End Function

Private Function EncryptDecrypt(ByVal data As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal encrypt As Boolean) As String

    #If Win64 Then
       Dim hHash As LongPtr
       Dim hKey  As LongPtr
       Dim hHashNull As LongPtr
       Dim hKeyNull As LongPtr

       hHashNull = 0&
       hKeyNull = 0&

    #Else
       Dim hHash As Long
        Dim hKey As Long
        Dim hHashNull As Long
       Dim hKeyNull As Long
    #End If


    Dim lLength As Long
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim GetValue As Boolean

    If hCryptProv = 0 Then
        HandleError "Not connected to CSP"
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    'The data will be encrypted with a session key derived from the
    'password.
    'The session key will be recreated when the data is decrypted
    'only if the password used to create the key is available.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Create a hash object.
    GetValue = CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_MD5, hKeyNull, 0, hHash)

    If GetValue = False Then
        HandleError "Error during CryptCreateHash!"
    End If

    'Hash the password.
    If CryptHashData(hHash, Password, Len(Password), 0) = 0 Then
        HandleError "Error during CryptHashData."
    End If

    'Derive a session key from the hash object.
    If CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM, hHash, 0, hKey) = 0 Then
        HandleError "Error during CryptDeriveKey!"
    End If

    'Do the work
    sTemp = data
    lLength = Len(data)
    If encrypt Then
        'Encrypt data.
        If CryptEncrypt(hKey, hHashNull, True, 0, sTemp, lLength, lLength) = 0 Then
            HandleError "Error during CryptEncrypt."
        End If
    Else
        'Encrypt data.
        GetValue = CryptDecrypt(hKey, hHashNull, True, 0, sTemp, lLength)
        If GetValue = 0 Then
            HandleError "Error during CryptDecrypt."
        End If
    End If

    'This is what we return.
    EncryptDecrypt = Mid$(sTemp, 1, lLength)

    'Destroy session key.
    If hKey <> 0 Then
        CryptDestroyKey hKey
    End If

    'Destroy hash object.
    If hHash <> 0 Then
        CryptDestroyHash hHash
    End If
End Function

Private Sub HandleError(ByVal error As String)
    'You could write the error to the screen or to a file
    Debug.Print error
End Sub

Private Function ByteToStr(ByRef ByteArray() As Byte, ByVal lLength As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ByteArray) To (LBound(ByteArray) + lLength)
        ByteToStr = ByteToStr & Chr$(ByteArray(i))
    Next i
End Function

Private Function EncryptNumber(ByVal lNumber As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sNumber As String

    sNumber = Format$(lNumber, "00000000")

    For i = 1 To 8
        EncryptNumber = EncryptNumber & Chr$(Asc(Mid$(NUMBER_ENCRYPT_PASSWORD, i, 1)) + Val(Mid$(sNumber, i, 1)))
    Next i
End Function

Private Function DecryptNumber(ByVal sNumber As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 8
        DecryptNumber = (10 * DecryptNumber) + (Asc(Mid$(sNumber, i, 1)) - Asc(Mid$(NUMBER_ENCRYPT_PASSWORD, i, 1)))
    Next i
End Function
```